# Different results for Visible formulas between Preview vs. Published app

Tags: google-app-maker

My formulas in Display --> visible seem to work while I am in Preview mode.  But don't work when I access a Published version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is somehow related to permissions configuration. In `Preview` mode you are always `Admin`. By default, when you create custom `Deployment` you are member of `Admin` role, but if you made some changes to default `Deployment' configuration it can result into the issue you are observing.